# Can bridge rectifier diodes fail in a way that allows AC through?

Tags: diodes, bridge-rectifier

KBPC5010 bridge rectifier: A new gate opener which worked for two weeks suddenly stopped working.

I notice that the DC motors buzzed like DC motors without a direction impulse (usually a start capacitor.)

I tested them by connecting them to a 24 V DC battery.  They worked fine, so I looked at the rectifier for the 230 V to 24 V AC transformer. I disconnected the 24 V AC supply from the transformer and connected the system to the alternative 24 V DC supply and it's working for now.

Is it possible for the rectifier diodes to break in a way that allows 24 V AC through, rather than nothing? I've ordered a couple of 5010s, but maybe I should be looking further, like maybe for a faulty capacitor near it.

Comment: Welcome! Please add a schematic and try to focus on what and how you have measured. If it's usage of an existing product and not something you have designed, this question is unfortunately off-topic here.

Answer (score 3):

A diode can fail shorted, though they more often fail open.

A bridge rectifier contains four diodes:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1jOIU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For there to be no current to the motor at all, at least two diodes in the bridge would have to fail open.

If one diode fails open, the motor will still get current but it will be in pulses.  Those pulses may not deliver enough current to get the motor turning.  The pulses could cause the motor to buzz.

If one or more diode failed short circuit, then you would also get buzzing.

The rectifier may have gotten too hot and failed.  The  [KBPC5010](http://www.eicsemi.com/datasheet/KBPC5000_10.pdf) is rated for 50A continuous, but that requires a rather large heat sink.  The datasheet mentions a finned heat sink 9 inches by 5 inches by 4.6 inches in size.  If your motor draws a lot of current, then the rectifier may need a larger heat sink than was originally installed.

---

You can test a bridge rectifier with a multimeter that has a diode check function.

1. Disconnect the bridge from the circuit entirely.
2. Connect the black probe of the multimeter to the minus (-) terminal of the rectifier.
3. Connect the red probe of the multimeter to the plus (+) terminal of the rectifier.
4. The meter should show about 1.4V.

If the meter shows much less than 1.4V then there may be a diode shorted.  If it shows a lot more than 1.4V (or shows out of range) then there is a diode open circuit.

Comment: Thank you JRE for your clear and kind answer. I think I may be on the right track. The gate motors do not draw very much at all, however there is no heat sink at all.....I think I'll fit one to the new one.